# "It was not before several years since/after" construction...is this even correct?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

I am writing a text and I have a doubt related to the construction of a sentence. I am not sure whether this is an idiomatic expression in English, or simply a commonly used construction (if even).

If that's an excuse, my first language is not English, but Portuguese!

So here it is:

> It was not before several years since/after the first meta-analysis had shown the thrombolytic drugs to be effective in the secondary prevention of mortality, that the experts started recommending such therapy with consistency.

My main doubt is: is this "it was not before several years since/after" correct?

If it's correct, is it elegant? Or too rocambolesque?

Thank you!

Claudia

Comment: "It was not until several years after..."?

Comment: Thank you, I think that's probably the most appropriate way to write it. But is the "before...since/after" correct as well?

Comment: You might also write: "It was only several years after the....."

Comment: It *is* grammatically correct; only that it would be better if they followed @Keepthesemind's suggestion instead of confusing common readers by adding *before* and *after* in the same clause.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Ébe. Does the "before...after" construction have the same meaning as the "until...since"?

Comment: @RonaldSole thank you! I took note of your suggestion.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac  I agree with you. And even less confusing is the suggestion that excludes the negative. Thank you everyone for such quick and objective answers!

Comment: @RonaldSole That would indicate that things happened quite soon/swiftly, whereas I read the original as indicating that it took quite a bit longer (than one would expect).